jenkins microsoftsqlserver
Tengo un pipeline de jenkins que clona un repo git, lo mete en el workspace, lo compila con maven y lo despliega a nexus y wildfly y me falta un ultimo paso que es que tengo que ejecutar un script en la BBDD MicrosoftSQLServer que está en una carpeta del workspace de jenkins y me está fallando. Tengo las credenciales, tengo las tools y este es el script:
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato, en la pregunta misma. Pon además un título descriptivo a la pregunta: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.
